# Adjust date on x-axis for fpp3 autoplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting, fable-r, tsibble

A quick reprex from the [book's website](https://otexts.com/fpp3/time-plots.html):

```r
melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers/1000)
autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
       subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
       y = "Passengers ('000)")
```

[image]

Note the x-axis has unusually formatting based on the week index. What I would like to do is adjust this, such as showing the year only (1989, 1990, 1991, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The `Week` column in the tibble is `yearweek` class.

```
R> class(melsyd_economy$Week)
[1] "yearweek"   "vctrs_vctr"
```

You can use `scale_x_yearweek` from `tsibble` package (contained within `fpp3`) with `autoplot` and design the x-axis label you want. Here's an example with just year:

```
library(fpp3)

melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers/1000)

autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
       subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
       y = "Passengers ('000)",
       x = "Year") +
  scale_x_yearweek(date_labels = "%Y")
```

**Plot**

[image: autoplot with specified date_labels using scale_x_yearweek]